# Received memory warning & crash when adding a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uilabel, custom-keyboard

I have simple emoji keyboard application, which allows the user to select keys and choose emojis to be pasted. They can also resize emojis using a slider. The code works well, but if I introduce a `UILabel` that shows the new size, then it receives a memory warning and crashes the app.

Here is code for the `UILabel` change on the `sliderValueChanged:` event:

```
-(IBAction)sizeChangedAction:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider*)sender;
    float value = slider.value;
    CGPoint center = self.imgResize.center;

    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(value, value);

    self.imgResize.transform = t;
    self.imgResize.center = center;
    myStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.fx%.f",value*210,value*210];
    _lblSize.text = myStr;
    myStr = nil;
}
```

Please point out where I made a mistake.

Comment: Where do you define `myStr` ?

Comment: I think he makes it global @Randy

Comment: ```CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(value, value);```
Do you think the value is too big ?

Comment: @DungProton This line makes memory warning :     _lblSize.text = myStr; if i remove it then everything works perfect!

Comment: @Randy     _lblSize.text = myStr; makes it crash! myStr is simply variable!

Comment: How you declare `myStr` ?

Comment: @DungProton its simple variable, even if i dont use mystr & assign values then also it crashes. Do you have any idea about UILabel & memory leak?

Comment: Can you NSLog `myStr` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115796/discussion-between-khatri-abdul-and-dungproton).